# Soap Fault VersionMismatch KSOAP2 for Android

Tags: android, soap, soapui, ksoap2

I'm trying to access a Web Service which is hosted here

http://srilanka.lk:9080/services/CropServiceProxy?wsdl

Works in SoapUI ok. I get the proper response in it.

**SoapUI Request**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <v1:getCropDataList>
         <v1:code>ABK</v1:code>
      </v1:getCropDataList>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SoapUI Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getCropDataListResponse xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/">
         <ns1:cropInfo>
            <ns1:name>Ambul Kesel</ns1:name>
            <ns1:price>35.0</ns1:price>
            <ns1:location>Dambulla</ns1:location>
         </ns1:cropInfo>
         <ns1:cropInfo>
            <ns1:name>Ambul Kesel</ns1:name>
            <ns1:price>40.0</ns1:price>
            <ns1:location>Dambulla</ns1:location>
         </ns1:cropInfo>
      </ns1:getCropDataListResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But in Ksoap2 for android the soap response is an error. Following are the requestDump and responseDump respectively.

**requestDump**

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<n0:getCropDataList id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/"> 
<code i:type="d:string">CNT</code>
</n0:getCropDataList>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

**responseDump**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:3257ABC779195052D01293913466558</wsa:RelatesTo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>VersionMismatch</faultcode>
<faultstring>Only SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2 messages are supported in the system</faultstring>
<detail />
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my code.

```
public void btnOnClick(View v){
        String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/";
        String URL = "http://220.247.225.202:9080/services/CropServiceProxy.CropServiceProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint";

        String METHOD_NAME = "getCropDataList";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/getCropDataList";

        SoapObject soap_request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        soap_request.addProperty("code", "ABK" );

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap_request);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "cropInfo", CropInfo.class);
        envelope.dotNet=false;

        Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
        floatMarshal.register(envelope);

        System.out.println("body out : " + envelope.bodyOut.toString());

        AndroidHttpTransport http_transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        //HttpTransportSE http_transport  = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        http_transport.debug = true;
        try {
            http_transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);         

            //because we should expect a vector, two kinds of prices are given
            Vector<CropInfo> result_array = (Vector<CropInfo>)envelope.getResponse();
            if(result_array != null){
                for (CropInfo current_crop: result_array){
                    System.out.println(current_crop.getName());
                    System.out.println(Float.toString(current_crop.getPrice()));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            answer.setText("error caught");
            System.out.print("REQUEST: ");
            System.out.println(http_transport.requestDump);
            System.out.print("RESPONSE: ");
            System.out.println(http_transport.responseDump);
        }



    }
```

How can I get a proper response in Ksoap2 for this?

Comment: did you try using version 1.1?

Comment: just my 5 cents - it is very risky to do all the stuff in a click listener, because it runs on the main UI thread. so the UI is blocked on a period untill the whole code has run. imagine a case with a bad radio coverage (low network speed) - it is very easy to get a ANR (application not responding) error popup. to avoid this the click listener should start some other (non-UI) `Thread`, or I would prefer to use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: 1.1 gives the following error. <soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement code</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault>

Comment: Thanks Arhimed, I'm gonna implement this as an AsyncTask. But first I have to get this service to respond. I don't know what's making this produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 1.1 and check out the error message. Something in axis2 on the server side is having a problem with the code subelement. Might just be that you have to set implicitTypes to false. Try some of the options on the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one specification for the SOAP standard, currently you're trying to send a request using SOAP 1.2 standard as you can see here

> SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

To fix, you should send your request as a SOAP 1.1 standard like this:

> SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting the namespace of the code object. You need to make sure you either set the target namespace to http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/ or add n0 namespace to the code element.

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"         xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <n0:getCropDataList id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://schemas.icta.lk/xsd/crop/handler/v1/"> 
      <n0:code i:type="d:string">CNT</code>
    </n0:getCropDataList>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```